# Quartz Scheduler to send email notification for failure jobs with the status

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have multiple jobs running in different time interval, my issue is some jobs got failed and I noticed it when I login into web portal to check the jobs. Is there any way to config so we get email alert if any job failed. I am using `quartz:1.0-RC9` and my `QuartzConfig.groovy` is ..

```
quartz {
autoStartup = true
jdbcStore = false
waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown=false
}

environments {
test {
quartz {
  autoStartup = false
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality, but you can do it very fast, with **mail plugin**.

**1.)** Add such string to your BuildConfig.groovy :

```
 plugins {
   ....
   runtime ":mail:1.0.1"
 }
```

**2.)** Add to your email and password Config.groovy:
For example here is how you would configure the default sender to send with a Gmail account:

```
grails {
   mail {
     host = "smtp.gmail.com"
     port = 465
     username = "youracount@gmail.com"
     password = "yourpassword"
     props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                     
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
              "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
   }
}
```

**3.)** Than you can add sending email in your job, for example:

```
class YourJob {
  static triggers = {
     simple repeatInterval: 5000l // execute job once in 5 seconds
  }

  //Adding service from plugin
 def mailService

 def execute() {
     try{
     //CODE that can fail
     }catch(e){

         mailService.sendMail {                
             to "my@gmail.com"
             subject "Failed"
             html "THIS JOB IS FAILED"
         }


       }
    }
}
```

**or**
 You can move it in some service for example MessageService and than you can do like that:

```
try{
//JOB CODE THAT CAN FAIL
} catch(e){
 messageService.sendFailedJobEmail()
}
```

More info about using plugin https://grails.org/plugin/mail